# PicoCTF Python Wrangling Challenge import error

Tags: python, ctf

When attempting the PicoCTF Python Wrangling Challenge linked below, I get an error when attempting any of the commands in the python general commands menu.

https://play.picoctf.org/practice/challenge/166

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ende.py", line 4, in <module>
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
ImportError: No module named cryptography.fernet
```

I have tried installing modules to see if I am missing something like: pip install cryptography but with no success. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The issue went away when I used "python3" instead of "python"